# doesn't loading home page and new project page when I deleted the directory of projects

Tags: unity-game-engine

the unity doesn't load the home page like picture

[image]

what can I do?

Answer (score 0):

On one of my computers Unity was blocked by firewall. When I removed the restriction from Unity, it started working. Maybe you should try the same.

If this will not help, probably you should download other version of Unity. On my computer with an old GPU some versions didn't run entirely, some didn't displayed anything but window border.

Answer (score 0):

I recommend you to download the [Unity Hub](https://unity3d.com/es/get-unity/download) program to handle things like these, there you can also download components for Unity.

And most importantly, you can migrate from old Unity 5 and into Unity 2018.

Comment: what is the unity hub? and I turned off firewall it doesn't work

Comment: Unity Hub is a program that lets you have multiple versions of Unity, and right now its the official way to have your Unity versions, I think it is less buggy